# How would I compute this sum?

Tags: calculus, probability, partial-differential-equations

So I would to compute this integral which is coupled by a sum:

$$ \int_{x = 0}^{x = \lambda} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} )^2} dx$$

I was thinking about using parseval's theorem to solve this integral but it doesn't quite work. I think a technique from PDEs does work but I am not sure which one to use.

Comment: Are you familiar with Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Yes I am. I know it is written in that form? How will be useful for this problem.

Comment: May be, you could switch summation and integral.

Answer (score 2):

Define $u_k=x-k\lambda$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^\lambda \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left( \frac{x-k\lambda}{\sigma}\right)^2}dx
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{0}^\lambda  e^{-\left( \frac{x-k\lambda}{\sigma}\right)^2}dx\\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-k\lambda}^{-(k-1)\lambda}  e^{-\left( \frac{u_k}{\sigma}\right)^2}du_k\\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{k\lambda}^{(k+1)\lambda}  e^{-\left( \frac{u_k}{\sigma}\right)^2}du_k\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\left( \frac{u_k}{\sigma}\right)^2}du_k\\
&=\sigma\sqrt{\pi}
\end{align*}
$$
The main idea is that when you switch the order of the sum and the integration (if you want to be technical, you are allowed to do this because of Tonelli's theorem, using the fact that the function is non-negative), you realize that this is simply a split of the integration of a Gaussian distribution into length-$\lambda$ "slices". We used the fact that integrating each slice individually and summing it up is equivalent to integrating the whole function in one shot. The last line is of course because of the fact that the area under the Gaussian pdf is 1:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Start changing the orders $$\int_{x = 0}^{x = \lambda} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} \right)^2} dx=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\int_{x = 0}^{x = \lambda}  e^{-\left( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} \right)^2} dx$$ and now use, from Gaussian distribution,$$\int  e^{-\left( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} \right)^2} dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } ~\sigma ~ \text{erf}\left(\frac{x-k \lambda }{\sigma }\right)$$ $$\int_{x = 0}^{x = \lambda}  e^{-\left( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} \right)^2} dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }~ \sigma  \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{k \lambda }{\sigma
   }\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\lambda -k \lambda }{\sigma }\right)\right)$$ Remember that $\text{erf}(-x)=-\text{erf}(x)$; so appears a telescopic series and then $$\sum_{k=-n}^n\int_{x = 0}^{x = \lambda}  e^{-\left( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} \right)^2} dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }~ \sigma  \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{n \lambda }{\sigma
   }\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{(n+1) \lambda }{\sigma }\right)\right)$$ and the limit of $\text{erf}(x)$ is $1$ when $x$ goes to infinity.

Then the final result $\sqrt{\pi } ~\sigma$

Comment: @Ahaan S. Rungta. Thanks for editing ! Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Wow really awesome. Ugg forgot that erf is an odd function. So, dumb :p

Comment: Is there a way to compute the double derivative of $$  \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} )^2} $$ with respect to x. I just want to find the series of this function and I want to show that function converges as $\sigma$ becomes large

Comment: What do you mean by "double" derivative ? Is it the second derivative wrt to $x$ ? If $f(x)=e^{-( \frac{x-k \lambda}{\sigma} )^2}$, we have $$f'(x)=-\frac{2 (x-k \lambda ) e^{-\frac{(x-k \lambda )^2}{\sigma ^2}}}{\sigma ^2}$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{4 (x-k \lambda )^2 e^{-\frac{(x-k \lambda )^2}{\sigma ^2}}}{\sigma ^4}-\frac{2
   e^{-\frac{(x-k \lambda )^2}{\sigma ^2}}}{\sigma ^2}$$